# Understand how this Transformation Matrix works

Tags: c++, matrix, directx, transform, sfml

I'm using the Transform component of [SFML library](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transform.php) as a base for my code, but I'm not understanding how it works. We initialize it like a 3x3 matrix, representing translation, rotation, and scale, but then we use a 4x4 matrix to store it, and with some values hardcoded. Beginning with that, I can't understand all later operations.

I'm looking for someone who can explain to me how this script works. Thanks in advance!

**Transform.h**

```
class Transform
{
public:
    static const Transform Identity;

    Transform();
    Transform(
        float a00, float a01, float a02,
        float a10, float a11, float a12,
        float a20, float a21, float a22
    );

    const float* GetMatrix() const;
    Transform GetInverse() const;

    D3DXVECTOR2 TransformPoint(float x, float y) const;
    D3DXVECTOR2 TransformPoint(const D3DXVECTOR2& point) const;

    FloatRect TransformRect(const FloatRect& rectangle) const;

    Transform& Combine(const Transform& transform);

    Transform& Translate(float x, float y);
    Transform& Translate(const D3DXVECTOR2& offset);

    Transform& Rotate(float angle);
    Transform& Rotate(float angle, float centerX, float centerY);
    Transform& Rotate(float angle, const D3DXVECTOR2& center);

    Transform& Scale(float scaleX, float scaleY);
    Transform& Scale(float scaleX, float scaleY, float centerX, float centerY);
    Transform& Scale(const D3DXVECTOR2& factors);
    Transform& Scale(const D3DXVECTOR2& factors, const D3DXVECTOR2& center);

private:
    float _matrix[16];
};

Transform operator *(const Transform& left, const Transform& right);
Transform& operator *=(Transform& left, const Transform& right);
D3DXVECTOR2 operator *(const Transform& left, const D3DXVECTOR2& right);
bool operator ==(const Transform& left, const Transform& right);
bool operator !=(const Transform& left, const Transform& right);
```

**Transform.cpp**

```
const Transform Transform::Identity;

Transform::Transform()
{
    _matrix[0] = 1.f; _matrix[4] = 0.f; _matrix[8] = 0.f; _matrix[12] = 0.f;
    _matrix[1] = 0.f; _matrix[5] = 1.f; _matrix[9] = 0.f; _matrix[13] = 0.f;
    _matrix[2] = 0.f; _matrix[6] = 0.f; _matrix[10] = 1.f; _matrix[14] = 0.f;
    _matrix[3] = 0.f; _matrix[7] = 0.f; _matrix[11] = 0.f; _matrix[15] = 1.f;
}

Transform::Transform(
    float a00, float a01, float a02,
    float a10, float a11, float a12,
    float a20, float a21, float a22
)
{
    _matrix[0] = a00; _matrix[4] = a01; _matrix[8] = 0.f; _matrix[12] = a02;
    _matrix[1] = a10; _matrix[5] = a11; _matrix[9] = 0.f; _matrix[13] = a12;
    _matrix[2] = 0.f; _matrix[6] = 0.f; _matrix[10] = 1.f; _matrix[14] = 0.f;
    _matrix[3] = a20; _matrix[7] = a21; _matrix[11] = 0.f; _matrix[15] = a22;
}

const float* Transform::GetMatrix() const
{
    return _matrix;
}

Transform Transform::GetInverse() const
{
    float det = _matrix[0] * (_matrix[15] * _matrix[5] - _matrix[7] * _matrix[13]) -
        _matrix[1] * (_matrix[15] * _matrix[4] - _matrix[7] * _matrix[12]) +
        _matrix[3] * (_matrix[13] * _matrix[4] - _matrix[5] * _matrix[12]);

    if (det != 0.f)
    {
        return Transform((_matrix[15] * _matrix[5] - _matrix[7] * _matrix[13]) / det,
            -(_matrix[15] * _matrix[4] - _matrix[7] * _matrix[12]) / det,
            (_matrix[13] * _matrix[4] - _matrix[5] * _matrix[12]) / det,
            -(_matrix[15] * _matrix[1] - _matrix[3] * _matrix[13]) / det,
            (_matrix[15] * _matrix[0] - _matrix[3] * _matrix[12]) / det,
            -(_matrix[13] * _matrix[0] - _matrix[1] * _matrix[12]) / det,
            (_matrix[7] * _matrix[1] - _matrix[3] * _matrix[5]) / det,
            -(_matrix[7] * _matrix[0] - _matrix[3] * _matrix[4]) / det,
            (_matrix[5] * _matrix[0] - _matrix[1] * _matrix[4]) / det
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return Identity;
    }
}

D3DXVECTOR2 Transform::TransformPoint(float x, float y) const
{
    return D3DXVECTOR2(_matrix[0] * x + _matrix[4] * y + _matrix[12],
        _matrix[1] * x + _matrix[5] * y + _matrix[13]);
}

D3DXVECTOR2 Transform::TransformPoint(const D3DXVECTOR2& point) const
{
    return TransformPoint(point.x, point.y);
}

FloatRect Transform::TransformRect(const FloatRect& rectangle) const
{
    const D3DXVECTOR2 points[] =
    {
        TransformPoint(rectangle.left(), rectangle.top()),
        TransformPoint(rectangle.left(), rectangle.top() + rectangle.height()),
        TransformPoint(rectangle.left() + rectangle.width(), rectangle.top()),
        TransformPoint(rectangle.left() + rectangle.width(), rectangle.top() + rectangle.height())
    };

    float left = points[0].x;
    float top = points[0].y;
    float right = points[0].x;
    float bottom = points[0].y;

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if (points[i].x < left)   left = points[i].x;
        else if (points[i].x > right)  right = points[i].x;
        if (points[i].y < top)    top = points[i].y;
        else if (points[i].y > bottom) bottom = points[i].y;
    }

    return FloatRect(left, top, right - left, bottom - top);
}

Transform& Transform::Combine(const Transform& transform)
{
    const float* a = _matrix;
    const float* b = transform._matrix;

    *this = Transform(a[0] * b[0] + a[4] * b[1] + a[12] * b[3],
        a[0] * b[4] + a[4] * b[5] + a[12] * b[7],
        a[0] * b[12] + a[4] * b[13] + a[12] * b[15],
        a[1] * b[0] + a[5] * b[1] + a[13] * b[3],
        a[1] * b[4] + a[5] * b[5] + a[13] * b[7],
        a[1] * b[12] + a[5] * b[13] + a[13] * b[15],
        a[3] * b[0] + a[7] * b[1] + a[15] * b[3],
        a[3] * b[4] + a[7] * b[5] + a[15] * b[7],
        a[3] * b[12] + a[7] * b[13] + a[15] * b[15]);

    return *this;
}

Transform& Transform::Translate(float x, float y)
{
    Transform translation(1, 0, x,
        0, 1, y,
        0, 0, 1);

    return Combine(translation);
}

Transform& Transform::Translate(const D3DXVECTOR2& offset)
{
    return Translate(offset.x, offset.y);
}

Transform& Transform::Rotate(float angle)
{
    float rad = angle * 3.141592654f / 180.f;
    float cos = std::cos(rad);
    float sin = std::sin(rad);

    Transform rotation(cos, -sin, 0,
        sin, cos, 0,
        0, 0, 1);

    return Combine(rotation);
}

Transform& Transform::Rotate(float angle, float centerX, float centerY)
{
    float rad = angle * 3.141592654f / 180.f;
    float cos = std::cos(rad);
    float sin = std::sin(rad);

    Transform rotation(cos, -sin, centerX * (1 - cos) + centerY * sin,
        sin, cos, centerY * (1 - cos) - centerX * sin,
        0, 0, 1);

    return Combine(rotation);
}

Transform& Transform::Rotate(float angle, const D3DXVECTOR2& center)
{
    return Rotate(angle, center.x, center.y);
}

Transform& Transform::Scale(float scaleX, float scaleY)
{
    Transform scaling(scaleX, 0, 0,
        0, scaleY, 0,
        0, 0, 1);

    return Combine(scaling);
}

Transform& Transform::Scale(float scaleX, float scaleY, float centerX, float centerY)
{
    Transform scaling(scaleX, 0, centerX * (1 - scaleX),
        0, scaleY, centerY * (1 - scaleY),
        0, 0, 1);

    return Combine(scaling);
}

Transform& Transform::Scale(const D3DXVECTOR2& factors)
{
    return Scale(factors.x, factors.y);
}

Transform& Transform::Scale(const D3DXVECTOR2& factors, const D3DXVECTOR2& center)
{
    return Scale(factors.x, factors.y, center.x, center.y);
}

Transform operator *(const Transform& left, const Transform& right)
{
    return Transform(left).Combine(right);
}

Transform& operator *=(Transform& left, const Transform& right)
{
    return left.Combine(right);
}

D3DXVECTOR2 operator *(const Transform& left, const D3DXVECTOR2& right)
{
    return left.TransformPoint(right);
}

bool operator ==(const Transform& left, const Transform& right)
{
    const float* a = left.GetMatrix();
    const float* b = right.GetMatrix();

    return ((a[0] == b[0]) && (a[1] == b[1]) && (a[3] == b[3]) &&
        (a[4] == b[4]) && (a[5] == b[5]) && (a[7] == b[7]) &&
        (a[12] == b[12]) && (a[13] == b[13]) && (a[15] == b[15]));
}

bool operator !=(const Transform& left, const Transform& right)
{
    return !(left == right);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a very broad question, so this is likely to be marked as 'off-topic'

The key insight here is why a 3x3 matrix is being encoded as a 4x4. This is due to the use of [homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). This is a mathematical solution that allows you to not only encode [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) such as rotation, scaling, and translation, it also supports projective transforms commonly used for 3D views. You can then multiply all the 4x4 matrices to get the transformations all concatenated into one multiply.

> In homogenous coordinates to get back to '3D' coordinates, you do a 4-vector * 4x4-matrix multiply and then divide the result by the 'w' element to get it back to [x y z 1].

4x4 homogenous matrices are organized so that the standard 3x3 matrix embeds into it. That's what this ctor does for example:

```
Transform::Transform(
    float a00, float a01, float a02,
    float a10, float a11, float a12,
    float a20, float a21, float a22
)
```

The actual layout of the matrix in memory for this library seems a little odd, but that's a question for the authors.

> 4x4 matrices also align better in memory on most platforms than 3x3 matrices, particularly when using SIMD operations that are usually 2-wide or 4-wide float vectors. Some systems have 4x3 matrices with an implicit [0 0 0 1] column/row which both provide nice alignment and a little more compact for affine transformations.

See also [DirectXMath](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath) and it's [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for another example of this style of graphics-focused math library.

> There are numerous introductory texts on 3D graphics that all cover the basics of the 3D graphics transformation pipeline using homogenous coordinates with 4x4 matrices. If you have the access & means, you may find getting one of them useful.